# <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement error

Tags: python, numpy, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello I am trying to get information from my spotify account but when ı do this ı getting this error,please help me

error :<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="24a1bcc176b484321b0c833e5ace246e", element="038512d9-65a1-4f34-bdf0-4dc5fcd07c77")>

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# start web driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver")
# get source code
driver.get("https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7pqM33R7ypG8dqxvna6VB7")
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.maximize_window()

login_form = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('main-view-container__scroll-node-child')
print(login_form)

# close web driver
driver.close()
```

Comment: it doesnt find the element by class, the class name is wrong. show us the `error message` in order to understand the problem

Comment: <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="24a1bcc176b484321b0c833e5ace246e", element="038512d9-65a1-4f34-bdf0-4dc5fcd07c77")> this is the error

Comment: put the traceback in your post to see where it came from.

Comment: I am trying to find this class "main-view-container__scroll-node-child"  with "driver.find_elements_by_class_name" code what is the wrong ? I cant find it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thats not an error , it is the **webelement list object** that you are printing in the print(login_form)

use something like:

```
print(login_form[0].text)
```